# Error Too many redirects causado por smarty

Tags: php, xampp, smarty

Un compañero de trabajo cambio el login de la pagina principal para que use Smarty, provocó el error de too many redirects y luego renuncio.

El error ocurre en el archivo login.php. Config.ini.php lo quite y no arregla el problema ya que config.ini.php esta exactamente igual a la versión vieja no desata ese error

```
<?php

/**
 * Login del Sistema
 *
 * @package Login
*/

require("../require/config.ini.php");
$smarty->display('login/index.tpl');
```

Estructura del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que se encuentra en require/config.ini.php por si es necesario. Este archivo no provocaba los problemas

```
<?php

session_start(); //Se activa al iniciar sesion con un usuario

require('../vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
$smarty = new Smarty;

//Se trae los templates de la carpeta eConnect2/templates
$smarty->setTemplateDir('../templates/'); 
$smarty->setCompileDir('../templates/templates_c/');
$smarty->setCacheDir('../templates/cache/');
$smarty->setConfigDir('../templates/configs/');

//Utiliza los archivos de la carpeta eConnect2/require
require("Conexion.php");
require("timeZone.php");
require("function.require.php");
require("menusmarty.require.php");
require("breadcrumbsmarty.require.php");
require('../php/combos.php');

//Si se tiene el DEV del .env en true se trae los archivos de las api y del econnect 
if (getenv('DEV') === 'true') {
    $smarty->assign("urlApi", "../../laravel_econnect/public/api/");
    $smarty->assign("urlImg", "../../laravel_econnect/public/econnect/");
//Si no los tiene, usa las url normales
}else {
    $smarty->assign("urlApi", "https://econnect.evolutionenergystudios.xyz/api/");
    $smarty->assign("urlImg", "https://econnect.evolutionenergystudios.xyz/api/");
}
```

Esto es lo que se encuentra en templates/login/index.tpl

```
{extends file='layout/layoutLogin.tpl'}
{block name="content"}
    <div class="appLogin">
        <form  id="login">
            <div class="alert" id="appLoginAlert" role="alert"></div>

                <div class="form-group" id="Usuario">
                    <label class="form-control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Usuario" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="Password">
                    <label class="form-control-label">Contraseña</label>
                    <input  autocomplete="off" type="password" name="Password" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-center padding-top-form">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-verde" name="botonlg" value="inicia sesión">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-center padding-top-form">
                    <a href="./signup.php">¿Nuevo cliente? Registrate</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
{/block}
```

Esto es lo que se encuentra en templates/layout/layoutLogin.tpl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        {include file="layout/head.tpl"}
        {include file="require/cssRequire.tpl"}
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--  GLobal -->
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$urlApi}}" id="api"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$urlImg}}" id="img"/>
        <div class="page-wrap">
            <!--  Menu -->
            {include file="layout/menu.tpl"}
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Loader -->
                <div class="loader" id="loader">Loading...</div>
                <!-- Border General -->
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            {block name= "content"}{/block}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {include file="layout/footer.tpl"}
        {include file="require/modalRequire.tpl"}
        {include file="require/jsRequire.tpl"}
        {block name="script"}{/block}
    </body>
</html>
```

EDICIÓN: Usando Vivaldi y bajando la velocidad de respuesta del navegador, me di cuenta de que los enlances tiran un error 302 que nunca se resuelve porque vuelve a intentar llamar al archivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que tiene el .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: No se ven redirecciones en tu código, habría que buscar si tienes algún `header('Location: ...');` en los scripts incluidos; aunque también podría ser cosa de apache, si tienes `.htaccess` para crear URL's amigables.

Comment: Encontre unos headers pero no estan fuera de los parametros normales, debe ser mi XAMPP